# How to fasten going through all independent variable combinations?

Tags: r, loops, optimization, time

I want to write function `combination_rsquare(y, data, factor_number)` where

`y` - A vector - dependent variable

`data` - A data frame containing independent variables

`factor_number` - vector or numeric which tells how many elements in combination should be included.

Let's consider my function :

```
combination_rsquare <- function(y, data, factor_number = c(2, 3)) {
  name_vec <- c()
  r_sq     <- c()
  for (j in seq_along(factor_number)) {
    # Defining combinations
    comb_names <- combn(colnames(data), factor_number[j])
    for (i in 1:ncol(comb_names)) {
      #Append model r-squared for each combination
      r_sq<- append(
        r_sq,
        summary(lm(y ~ ., data = data[comb_names[1:factor_number[j], i]]))$r.squared
      )
      # Create vector containing model names seperated by "+"
      name_vec <- append(
        name_vec,
        paste(comb_names[1:factor_number[j], i], collapse = "+")
      )
    }
  }
  data.frame(name_vec, r_sq)
}
```

Let's have a look how my function works on data :

```
Norm <- rnorm(100)
Unif <- runif(100)
Exp  <- rexp(100)
Pois <- rpois(100,1)
Weib <- rweibull(100,1)
df <- data.frame(Unif, Exp, Pois, Weib)
combination_rsquare(Norm, df) 

         name_vec       r_sq
1        Unif+Exp 0.02727265
2       Unif+Pois 0.02912956
3       Unif+Weib 0.01613404
4        Exp+Pois 0.04853872
5        Exp+Weib 0.03252025
6       Pois+Weib 0.03573252
7   Unif+Exp+Pois 0.05138219
8   Unif+Exp+Weib 0.03571401
9  Unif+Pois+Weib 0.04112936
10  Exp+Pois+Weib 0.06209911
```

Okay - so we have it! Everything is working! However - If I'm putting very large data frame to my function and adding new features to be calculated (adjusted R.squared, AIC, BIC and so on) it's taking ages! My question is - is there any possibility how can I make this function works faster ? i.e. maybe the double loop can be omitted, or maybe there is R build function for creating such combinations ?

To summarize - How can I make `combination_rsquare()` to calculate faster ?

Comment: Use lm.fit instead of lm and calculate R squared using cor(y, fitted(fm))^2 . Also check out the ExhaustiveSearch package.

Comment: Okay, and do you reckon that code will be significantly faster due to these things ? ;))

Comment: Or just faster ?

Comment: You will have to test it.